# How can I whitelist URLs in phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm creating an app for iOS using phonegap and I'm trying to access my JSON api through an ajax request. But I get the following error:

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://app.nickverheijen.nl/api/v1/paintings/all'
```

I've followed the documentation and in there it states that I should add the URL to my config.xml.

I have added these lines to the config.xml file in both the root "www" directory and in the iOS specific "www" directory:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="http://app.nickverheijen.nl*" />
```

But it still gives me the same error. I've looked around on the web and on here and tried some "solutions" but none of them worked. Does anyone know what I should do or what I'm doing wrong?

BTW, I'm using Cordova version 3.2.0-0.2.0

Comment: Remove the asterisk <access origin="http://app.nickverheijen.nl" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whitelisting presumes all subpages by default, so remove the `*` in the second line:

```
<access origin="http://app.nickverheijen.nl" />
```